# Changing css on multiple objects according to scroll position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to highlight the link in a sticky header that corresponds to the div currently scrolled to. I've tried my best to find solutions on the net, but haven't found anything. Maybe I've been using the wrong keywords, so forgive me if this has been answered already. I am also aware of Bootstrap's Scrollspy, however, something in my website prevents it from working. Oh dear... something's gone terribly wrong.

In any case I'd be grateful if you could have a look at the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Eh5L9/9/

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".panel").each(function() {
        var eidee = this.attr('id'),
            thetop = this.offset().top,
            thebottom = this.offset.top + this.height();            
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > thetop && $(document).scrollTop() < thebottom) {
            $('#menu link' + eidee).addClass('bla');
        }   
        else {
            $('#menu link' + eidee).removeClass('bla');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: do you know what prevents Scrollspy from working? re-inventing the wheel sucks.

Comment: well for starters your `$('.panel').each(function()` is spelled wrong

Comment: u got many many tipos.. underline instead of underlined, function instead of funtion, attr('id') instead of id, no jquery added, $(this) instead of this and many more.. you can just drop this javascript..

Comment: @dave-briand I think it has something to do with this:

Comment: @gulty how ironic your spelling `typo` itself is a typo

Comment: @dave-briand I think it has something to do with this: when I declared the `<!DOCTYPE html>` & thus put on standards mode I had a problem with the `<html>` and `<body>` tags wrapping to the content. The solution was to add css `html, body {height:100%;}`, however the body part of that broke the functionality of the webkitty `position: sticky;`... So I worked around it with `$(".panel").css("min-height", $("html").height());` as soon as the document is ready or when the page resizes. This lets the body wrap as it likes without squashing the content divs.

Answer (score 0):

besides the bunch of typos here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eh5L9/6/

I changed the CSS menu to be displayed at the bottom so you can see that it works. Still there is better way to write this code - its working anyway..

JS:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".panel").each(function(){ 
        var eidee = $(this).attr('id'),
            thetop = $(this).offset().top,
            thebottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();    
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > thetop && $(document).scrollTop() < thebottom) {
            $('#menu').find('#link' + eidee).addClass('bla');
        }   
        else {
            $('#menu').find('#link' + eidee).removeClass('bla');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: neater - this obviously works so it's alight - the wording is bad tho (eidee for instance) - also for compatibility reasons it would have been better not to reinvent the wheel. this is just a small function therefor it's okay tho :) and btw. you can mark the question as answered - no upvote needed :)

Comment: here's the same fiddle with position set to fixed and top instead of absolute. http://jsfiddle.net/Eh5L9/10/